# How to set cursor position to end of text in CKEditor?

Tags: ckeditor, fckeditor

Is there a way to set the cursor to be at the end of the contents of a CKEditor?

This developer asked too, but received no answers:

http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=19877&hilit=cursor+end

I would like to set the focus at the end of the text inside a CKEditor. When I use:

```
ckEditor.focus();
```

It takes me to the beginning of the text already inside the CKEditor.

Answer (score 25):

Dan's answer got strange results for me, but minor change (in addition to typo fix) made it work:

```
var range = me.editor.createRange();
range.moveToElementEditEnd( range.root );
me.editor.getSelection().selectRanges( [ range ] );
```

Comment: Thanks, same here. Dan's solution did insert the caret for me, but at the right-most point in the editor in line with the expected end point. Yours has fixed it, thanks.

Comment: Thanks this works.. now to figure out how to programatically enter the editor (focus doesn't bring a caret up)

Comment: in my case, the code set's the caret at the end, but didn't scroll to the end. So I could see only the caret, when I used the scrollbars to go to the end. I helped myself with 

  me.editor.insertHtml("");

and that did the job.

Answer (score 12):

According to the documentation for CKEditor 4, you can do the following once you have the editor object.

```
var range = editor.createRange();
range.moveToPosition( range.root, CKEDITOR.POSITION_BEFORE_END );
editor.getSelection().selectRanges( [ range ] );
```

Link: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.selection (under selectRanges function).

Comment: What the heck is `[ranges]`?? Is the "s" a typo?

Comment: @Mark, thanks for the catch. It should be `range`. That's what I get for not verifying the CKEditor documentation.

Comment: I wasn't quite sure because the square-bracket syntax makes it almost look like a placeholder for something different.

Comment: Unfortunately, not the cleanest of code. For anyone that's not familiar with JavaScript, `selectRanges` accepts an array of [`CKEDITOR.dom.range`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.range) objects, and `[range]` creates an array with only the `range` object in it.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out, but the typo through me off :-) Most of those CKEDITOR objects seem to be thin wrappers around the native equivalents.

Comment: @Dan and anyone - whenever you find a bug in the documentation feel free to either report it @ http://dev.ckeditor.com or in case of typos simply create a pull request @ https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev

Comment: So where exactly are you guys putting this code at??

Comment: @Yokhannan: you can run this in a button click handler if your editor is already initialised - get the editor instance from `CKEDITOR.instances.your_name` if necessary. If you are running this code within page initialisation, you'll need to do it within the `instanceReady` CKEditor event, otherwise it will try to assign focus before the editor is able to accept it.

Comment: Unfortunatly it doesn't seems to work anymore with 4.4.8. maybe a bug. Not sure.

Answer (score 5):

After a bit of fiddling, I've got it to work with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(ev) {

        ev.editor.focus();

        var s = ev.editor.getSelection(); // getting selection
        var selected_ranges = s.getRanges(); // getting ranges
        var node = selected_ranges[0].startContainer; // selecting the starting node
        var parents = node.getParents(true);

        node = parents[parents.length - 2].getFirst();

        while (true) {
            var x = node.getNext();
            if (x == null) {
                break;
            }
            node = x;
        }

        s.selectElement(node);
        selected_ranges = s.getRanges();
        selected_ranges[0].collapse(false);  //  false collapses the range to the end of the selected node, true before the node.
        s.selectRanges(selected_ranges);  // putting the current selection there
    }

});
```

The idea is:

1. Get the root node (not body)
2. Advance to next node, until there are no more nodes to advance to.
3. Select last node.
4. Collapse it
5. Set range

Answer (score 4):

Here's a similar answer to @peter-tracey. In my case my plugin is inserting a citation.  If the user has made a selection, I needed to disable the selection and place the cursor at the end of the sentence.

```
  // Obtain the current selection & range
  var selection = editor.getSelection();
  var ranges = selection.getRanges();
  var range = ranges[0];

  // Create a new range from the editor object
  var newRange = editor.createRange();

  // assign the newRange to move to the end of the current selection
  // using the range.endContainer element.
  var moveToEnd = true;
  newRange.moveToElementEditablePosition(range.endContainer, moveToEnd);

  // change selection
  var newRanges = [newRange];
  selection.selectRanges(newRanges);

  // now I can insert html without erasing the previously selected text.
  editor.insertHtml("<span>Hello World!</span>");
```

Answer (score 2):

CKEditor 3.x:

```
on : {
        'instanceReady': function(ev) {
           ev.editor.focus();
           var range = new CKEDITOR.dom.range( ev.editor.document );
           range.collapse(false);
           range.selectNodeContents( ev.editor.document.getBody() );
           range.collapse(false);
           ev.editor.getSelection().selectRanges( [ range ] );
        }
     }
```

based on pseudo-code provided by the developers here:

https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9546#comment:3

> You have to focus editor, get document object, put it in range,
>   collapse range (with false parameter), select body (with
>   selectNodeContents), collapse it (with false parameter) and finally
>   select range. It is best to do it all in instanceReady event.

Answer (score 1):

This is the easiest solution provided by the ckeditor API. I have tested it on IE10+, ff, safari and Chrome:

```
range = editor.createRange();
// the first parameter is the last line text element of the ckeditor instance
range.moveToPosition(new CKEDITOR.dom.node(editor.element.$.children[pos - 1]), CKEDITOR.POSITION_BEFORE_END)
range.collapse()
editor.getSelection().selectRanges([ range ])
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work for sure.
CKEDITOR.config.startupFocus = 'end';

Comment: Worked for me in an Inline Ckeditor (4.11)  
+1 thank you

Answer (score 0):

have you tried ckEditor.Selection.Collapse(false);

Comment: I'm not seeing what call your talking about exactly. What's the precise syntax? I don't see a Selection field on my ckeditor object.

Answer (score 0):

According to CKEditor 4 documentation, another option is:

```
const range = this.ckeditor.createRange()
range.moveToElementEditablePosition(range.root, true)
this.ckeditor.getSelection().selectRanges([range])
```

Link: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_dom_range.html#method-moveToElementEditablePosition