# How to set selection in CKEditor5?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor5

After setting text in the editor, I need to set the focus to the end of the text. How to do it? I can not understand

```
editor.setData('text');
editor.editing.view.focus(); // focus to set the beginning, but on the end
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/ogm5s6k7/1/

```js
// Editor configuration.
ClassicEditor
  .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ))
  .then( editor => {
  window.editor = editor;
})
  .catch( error => {
  console.error( error );
});

document.getElementById('focusSet').onclick = function(e) {
  window.editor.setData('text');
  window.editor.editing.view.focus();
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/11.1.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
<div id="editor">
  <p>Editor content goes here.</p>
</div>
<br>
<button id="focusSet">Focus</button>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set cursor position to end of text in CKEditor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536532/how-to-set-cursor-position-to-end-of-text-in-ckeditor)

Comment: In that problem, the old version of editor 4

Comment: Did none of the solutions on that question work?

Comment: yes, does not work

Comment: Please modify the question to include a **[mcve]**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To set selection in CKE5, you need to do it in "change block" where you have an access to the writer:

```
editor.model.change( writer => {
    writer.setSelection( ... );
} );
```

There are a couple of ways to set selection, see docs: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_writer-Writer.html#function-setSelection

Basically, you need some reference when setting selection. For example, if you want to set it after a given model node, you need a reference to that node and then you can use it like this:

```
writer.setSelection( myNode, 'after' );
```

If you want to set it at the end of the content you can use the document root:

```
writer.setSelection( editor.model.document.getRoot(), 'end' );
```

Comment: The last one is really useful when you want to set autofocus at the end of CKE5. Just change selection to the end, after that just call `editor.editing.view.focus();`.